Ancor is not added correctly
Ancor is added after # to the main page (site.com/#ancor) - the site domain. But it needs to be added to the current page (site.com/category/article#ancor)
Apparently there is an error here
 generateNavEl: function(anchor, text) {
        var $a = $('<a class="nav-link"></a>');
        $a.attr("href", "#" + anchor);
        $a.text(text);
        var $li = $("<li></li>");
        $li.append($a);
        return $li;
      },

Код взят отсюда

All the properties the Location interface exposes, can be accessed directly on a link as well - when you go via the DOM, instead of jQuery.
$a[0].hash = "#" + anchor;

$a[0] gets the reference to the native DOM element wrapped in this jQuery instance.
And then only the hash portion of the location the link points to gets changed, leaving everything else, including the path, as it was.

Ok. Thanks. But how will my code change? - I don't understand where to insert it (

That replaces the line $a.attr("href", "#" + anchor);

Yes. I did so right away. But that's how adding an anchor stops working. Nothing happens when you click on the table of contents. Perhaps something is not working? thank you

Hard to say, based on just that tiny snippet you have shown. (For the next time you ask something: We like to see a proper [mre] of the issue, with this kind of question.) I'm guessing it is probably because you are creating the link yourself there, instead of working on links already contained in the document. You could try var $a = $('<a class="nav-link" href="#'+anchor+'"></a>'); instead.

I'm sorry. I haven't quite figured out how to format the questions yet. The post contains a link to the script itself. Here is an example that works. https://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc/. But my example doesn't work. I don't know if it's possible to leave links. https://sportswear.com.ua/index.php?route=octemplates/blog/oct_blogarticle&blogarticle_id=7&blog_path=2
